# Ignoring error in another project to run current one in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, intellisense, solution

I have a solution with several projects, let's say projects A, B and others.

Project A is not compiling. Project B is compiling fine and is set as StartUp project.

I can't run Project B until I fix Project A errors caught by Intellisense. And projects A and B share no references with each other whatsoever.

There is any way of run Project B without fixing Project A errors? I thought of disabling Intellisense, but that wouldn't be what I want.

I'm using C# with Visual Studio 2010, but if there is anything helpful on 2012 let me know too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered removing Project A from the solution temporarily

Comment: @CHill60 Yes, that would work but it could generate a little hassle. If Project A is referenced by Projects C and D I would have to remove those too. And when committing I'll have to add those back, or don't  commit the solution (but what if I altered something on the solution that I have to commit?).

Comment: You can simply `unload` project A by right clicking the project in the solution explorer and click `unload`. When you wish to continiue with project A, right click the project and click `reload`

Comment: @2pietjuh2 That generate 'less hassle' then removing'n'adding, good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the solution properties, make sure Project A is set to not build and Project B is set as start up, project B should launch without first trying to build Project A

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Project B has a dependency on Project A. If you think you don't reference Project A at all, right-click on Project B in System Explorer, select Project Dependencies, and untick Project A in the Depends On list.

Comment: There is no dependencies between the projects. Just checked.

Comment: Ok great then try what @Fredrik Bagge says - Build menu ->, Configuration Manager, untick Project A.